# DHTMLX GanttChart maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

We like to use DHTMLX Gantt Chart in our AngularJs1.6/Spring MVC/Tomcat server application.

Is there any maven dependency for DHTMLX ganttchart and/or DHTMLX GanttChart?

Most of the DHTMLX talks about connecting with Nodejs and not with Java Backend.

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX Gantt is a Javascript library, it doesn't depend on other libraries.
There are no guides for Java, but I have a demo for the Spring framework:
https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/e91d39e67e5136cc1671999d439c2465/Spring+Gantt_demo.zip